# Extending the EBS Volume in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

Currently i have created EBS Backed(30GB) EC2 Instance,  data in EBS has reached to almost maximum capacity.
   What would be best practice to increase the size of EBS volume with high availability
    a) Extend the existing EBS volume by taking snapshot
    b) Attach new EBS Volume

In case we extend the EBS volume we have to take snapshot ,then stop instance and recreate ebs volume with this snapshot.
Will EC2 Instance boot from newly created EBS volume.

Answer (score 0):

> Ideal Way of doing this !

**Yes** precisely you are thinking in the right direction.

You could automate it with **multiple sequential lambdas** or **bash** would be also an ideal solution to your query.

> How much should space should we increase?

Above will depend on your EBS storage filling rate. Make a wise choice accordingly.